# Problem with JSP getRemoteAddress

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, ip

I would like to find out how to get IP address of the client, that is visiting my web pages.
Content of JSP page:

```
<% 
out.print( request.getRemoteAddr() + "<br>");
out.print( request.getRemoteHost() ); 
%>
```

Output:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Comment: What OS are you running the server on?

Comment: If you are running Vista, you can disable IPv6 via instructions available at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852 . That does not change the behavior of getRemoteAddr() and getRemoteHost() though, so you could get the IP address as reported by a proxy or load balancer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" is the IPv6 loopback address as defined in [RFC 3513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513).

It appears that your OS and application server are configured to use IPv6 and that you are accessing the page from the local machine.

By the way, calling getRemoteAddress() will not provide you with the IP address of the client. There could be intermediate nodes in the network whose address you might receive. This is especially true of proxies and load-balancers.

Comment: But how can I Convert 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1  to exact IP.

Comment: @SatishSharma - It is already an exact IP.  (You have misunderstood the answer.)