# Get IP address of client in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, ip

I need to get the IP address of the client in the JSP page. I have tried the following ways:

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
request.getHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR")
request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP")
request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP")
request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP")
request.getHeader("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

However, none of those ways did return the desired IP address. How do I get the IP address of the client in the JSP page?

Comment: If you use custom header, always name them `X-<custom-name>`.

Comment: What does `request.getRemoteAddr()` return?

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1423347/473637) question.

Comment: request.getRemoteAddr() returns 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 which is not the true value of IP of client.

Comment: try request.getRemoteHost() method, if the client not use a gateway ip of client return by this method. else this method returns the ip of gateway.

Answer (score 13):

To get IP address of the client, I've used the following method

```
<%   String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");  
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
            ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");  
        }  
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
            ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");  
        }  
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");  
        }  
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");  
        }  
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
            ip = request.getRemoteAddr();  
        }
        %>
```

Hope this helps,
please leave a feed back.

Answer (score 8):

```
<%
out.print( request.getRemoteAddr() );
out.print( request.getRemoteHost() );
%>
```

You may not get the real client IP if a the client is behind a proxy, you will get the IP of the proxy and not the client. However, the proxy may include the requesting client IP in a special HTTP header.

```
<%
out.print( request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for") );
%>
```

Comment: But how to get The IP of client when no proxy is configured between client and requested server.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423347/problem-with-jsp-getremoteaddress) See this post.

Comment: output comes like 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 you have any idea why??

Answer (score 3):

Is your application server behind a load balancer, a proxy or a web server? Just an example; F5 load balancer exposes the client IP address with the "rlnclientipaddr" header:

```
request.getHeader("rlnclientipaddr");
```

Answer (score 0):

do you use reverse proxy like apache proxy?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

When acting in a reverse-proxy mode (using the ProxyPass directive, for example), mod_proxy_http adds several request headers in order to pass information to the origin server. These headers are:

```
X-Forwarded-For
The IP address of the client.
X-Forwarded-Host
The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
X-Forwarded-Server
The hostname of the proxy server.
```

Comment: No Proxy is used between server and client . All Values getting using X-Forwarded-For , X-Forwarded-Host , X-Forwarded-Server are giving null cause of proxy is not used.

Comment: if you are not using any of reverse proxy, just check use http servlet API - httpServletRequest.getRemoteHost() and getRemotePOrt()  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: Nothing is present in httpServletRequest that will provide me the IP of Client. I Have Checked The Whole API.