# request.getRemoteAddr() not working from linux

Tags: linux, jsp, tomcat

I have a jsp web application. I am setting the value of a hidden input using the code

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

to fill it with the client's IP address. When my webapp is deployed on tomacat/windows its giving me correct IP. but when the webapp is deployed to tomcat/linux, its giving me wrong IP address something like 10.0.xx.xx

How to fix it?

Comment: 10.0.xx.xx is a local IP, so I can assume it's IP address of your network gateway (or proxy or something similar) which routes client request to your linux tomcat. I think you can't fix getRemoteAddr() because it works properly.

Comment: Why should 10.0.xx.xx be wrong? Maybe you mean 1.0.0.0.... which would be an IP6 problem -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423347/problem-with-jsp-getremoteaddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is behind a proxy, you may be able to retrieve the original address using the [X_FORWARDED_FOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header:

```
request.getHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR");
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody, including yourself, has a proxy in front of this server, `getRemoteAddr()` will return the proxy's address, not the client's.